# How to convert jsonify string to json in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flutter, dart

I have a jsonify string as follows.
I have created this string using dart (Flutter).
My dart code is as follows.

```
 var stud_data = {"name": "John", "id": "2021MS", "total_marks": 493};
 String encoded_data = base64Url.encode(utf8.encode(stud_data.toString()));
```

encoded_data contains "e25hbWU6IEpvaG4sIGlkOiAyMDIxTVMsIHRvdGFsX21hcmtzOiA0OTN9
"

I have to convert it to json in python.

I tried following code to convert in json using python.

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64decode
import json
stud_data_64="e25hbWU6IEpvaG4sIGlkOiAyMDIxTVMsIHRvdGFsX21hcmtzOiA0OTN9"
stud_data=urlsafe_b64decode(string).decode('utf-8')
stud_data_json = json.loads(stud_data)
```

It results in the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

The error is clear to me, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `'{name: John, id: 2021MS,  total_marks: 493}'` is not valid JSON. How did you "jsonify" it in the first place.

Comment: I have jsonify it using dart.  In dart, this format can be converted to json easily.

Comment: Obviously you are not doing right. Show your code/ask about that part - that's where the root of the problem is. Your current code the parse the JSON string will work if it was valid JSON.

Comment: This is a base 64 converted string `data="e25hbWU6IEpvaG4sIGlkOiAyMDIxTVMsIHRvdGFsX21hcmtzOiA0OTN9"`.

Comment: I have to convert this.

Comment: I do not really think that that the conversion is done correctly because it seems like the keys are missing double quotes

Comment: this was not valid JSON before base64 encoding it. This was just a plain string `'{name: John, id: 2021MS,  total_marks: 493}'`

Comment: if you base64 encode string `{"name": "John", "id": "2021MS", "total_marks": 493}` the result is `eyJuYW1lIjogIkpvaG4iLCAiaWQiOiAiMjAyMU1TIiwgInRvdGFsX21hcmtzIjogNDkzfQ==`

Comment: Your dart side code is bad. import 'dart:convert', then do json.encode(stud_date) instead of toString()

Comment: `eyJuYW1lIjogIkpvaG4iLCAiaWQiOiAiMjAyMU1TIiwgInRvdGFsX21hcmtzIjogNDkzfQ==` is the true base64 string. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone has mentioned, you don't have a valid json string there.  The reason that you don't is because you're not converting your dart object to json.  You're just converting it to a string.  Change your dart code to:

```
String encoded_data = base64Url.encode(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(stud_data)));
```

Doing that will give you a valid json string which when converted to base64 will end up being:

```
eyJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiIsImlkIjoiMjAyMU1TIiwidG90YWxfbWFya3MiOjQ5M30=
```